# Get All Month in Group Header Section In Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I Have a ledger table to show in crystal report in month view dabit and credit record via group header
 but my table don't have Augest record..

so i want to show Augest record as dabit=0 and credit=0
as well as all empty months record..

kindly help

thanks

expample

```
month dabit credit 
jan   10     10 
feb   10     20 
apr   10     50
```

wanted view is

```
month  dabit  credit
jan     10      10
feb     10      20
mar     0        0 
apr     10      50
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be create a `View` with data for all months and values as `0` then left join the view with your table and use that in crystal report.